# Problemas de incio de sesion y registro, Firebase y Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-play

Tengo problemas con el inicio de sesion y el registro en mi aplicacion, ya publique mi aplicacion en play store y dejo de funcionar el inicio de sesion y el registro (antes de publicarla funcionaba a la perfeccion), ya vincule mi aplicacion de firebase a google play,y las claves sha estan bien y configuradas, nose que mas hacer, agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: asegurate que applicationId coincida

Comment: Donde puedo encontrar el applicationId?

Comment: En el archivo gradle. Fijate que sea el mismo en debug y en realease. Sin son distintos revisa que ambos esten agregados en el google-services.json

Comment: No funciono, y no encuentro la solucion, porfavor ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 cosas que identifican una aplicación android: el `package name` o applicationId y el `signing certificate` que generalmente se cifra usando SHA-1.

Con la configuración predeterminada, la variante release de tu app tiene el mismo applicationId que la variante debug pero revisalo por si acaso. El certificado necesariamente tiene que ser diferente.
Cada build variant de tu app que cambie una de esas 2 cosas es considerada una aplicación diferente y por lo tanto debes registrarla como tal en la consola de Firebase.

La otra configuración necesaria para usar Firebase es el archivo `google-services.json`. Este archivo contiene un array de las apps autorizadas a comunicarse con tu proyecto. Esto significa que cada vez que agregas una app tienes que volver a descargar este archivo y sobrescribir el anterior.

Esas 3 cosas resaltadas son las que debes que revisar. Si todo coincide, la autenticación tiene que funcionar.